# Como formatar campo date no datatables?

Tags: laravel, jquery-datatables, datatable

código atual

```
 return datatables()->of($query->get())
                        ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                            $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>';
                            $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                            $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                            return $button;
                        })
                        ->rawColumns(['action'])
                        ->make(true);
            }
```

> Tenho um campos vencimento_titulo sendo renderizado porém com o
>   formato Y/m/d gostaria de d/m/Y.

Answer (score 1):

```
->editColumn('vencimento_titulo', function ($data) {
            return $data->vencimento_titulo->format('d/m/Y');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente a saída do seu date-time está vindo em formato textual.

Para resolver isso você pode usar **strtotime()**, que recebe um date-time textual e converte em unix date-time e a função **date()**, que permite a formatação de preferência.

Fica assim:

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime(vencimento_titulo))
```